# CSS flexbox: How to fill the remaining screen height with a nested div?

Tags: css, flexbox

In this example, 
http://jsfiddle.net/ch7n6/1833/

```
<section id="container" >
<header id="header" >This is a header</header>
<article id="content" >
    This is the content that
    <br />
    With a lot of lines.
    <br />
    With a lot of lines.
    <br />
    This is the content that
    <br />
    With a lot of lines.
    <br />
    <br />
    This is the content that
    <br />
    With a lot of lines.
    <br />
    <br />
    This is the content that
    <br />
    With a lot of lines.
    <br />
</article>
<footer id="footer" >This is a footer</footer>
</section>
```

the "Article" could vary nicely according to the screen, however, in the following case, with an extra div wrapping the the article, it no longer works, could someone suggest ways to handle this? The reason I asked this question is that I am using Vuetify, so the div is heavily nested and I can't just following the working example to solve my problem.

```
<section id="container" >
<header id="header" >This is a header</header>
<div>
<article id="content" >
    This is the content that
    <br />
    With a lot of lines.
    <br />
    With a lot of lines.
    <br />
    This is the content that
    <br />
    With a lot of lines.
    <br />
    <br />
    This is the content that
    <br />
    With a lot of lines.
    <br />
    <br />
    This is the content that
    <br />
    With a lot of lines.
    <br />
</article>
</div>
<footer id="footer" >This is a footer</footer>
</section>
```

Comment: simply apply the style of article ot its div container

Comment: that should work, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ch7n6/1835/

Answer (score 0):

```
.flexbox {
 flex: 1 1 auto;
 overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Try this style in your div element.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;    
}

.flexbox {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}

#container header {
    background-color: gray;
}
#container article {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-height: 0px;
}
#container footer {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<section id="container" >
    <header id="header" >This is a header</header>
    <div class="flexbox">
    
     <article id="content" >
        This is the content that
        <br />
        With a lot of lines.
        <br />
        With a lot of lines.
        <br />
        This is the content that
        <br />
        With a lot of lines.
        <br />
        <br />
        This is the content that
        <br />
        With a lot of lines.
        <br />
        <br />
        This is the content that
        <br />
        With a lot of lines.
        <br />
    </article>
    </div>
    <footer id="footer" >This is a footer</footer>
</section>
```